# Linux - run command when display turns on to reset xsetwacom setting

Tags: linux, xorg, xfce, wacom-one

I'm using a Wacom one pen display, and to make the pen use the right monitor I need to run

```
ID=$(xsetwacom list | grep stylus | awk '{print $9}')
xsetwacom set "$ID" MapToOutput HEAD-1
```

Putting this command in `~/.xinitrc`, runs this when X11 starts up. However, whenever my screen blanks and then turns back on this setting is reset. My screen blanks after 20 minutes of inactivity, this is managed by `xfce4-power-manager`. (If relevant, I'm using Manjaro with XFCE).

Is there a way to catch the event of the display turning on and running a script? Or otherwise is it possible to prevent the setting from getting reset in the first place? Searching in the source code of `xfce4-power-manager` seems to imply it uses `xscreensaver` to do the display blanking (not `dpms`).

My current workaround is running the command every minute using `crontab`, but a real solution would be better.

Comment: In case someone wants to use my `crontab` workaround, be sure to add something like this to your script:
`export DISPLAY=":0"`, and
`export XAUTHORITY="~/.Xauthority"`.
Otherwise when running a script as a cron job it will not have access to the displays.